# Replying the rejection email from Professor

Tags: phd, email

Recently I mailed a professor for a PhD position and got a reply after two days.
The following is the reply I received from the prof.

> I am afraid we already found a candidate to fill this position.
>       There will be other opportunities in the future in our group.
>       We are truly sorry for not bringing more positive news, and I would like 
>       wish you the best on your job search.

A thank you and good luck reply is needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reply needed from you to them.

Move on to your other applications.

Comment: +1. Professors get hundreds of emails each day, no need for small talk.